# How to run module code on a specific page/path?

Tags: 7

So, I'm working on an implementation where users will be redirected to a specific path on a Drupal 7 site with query parameters appended to the URL in an Oauth2 scenario (e.g. www.mysite.com/mypath&code&scope) which the D7 should process and respond to. How does one specify within a custom module to run the code a particular path? Would this be achieved through a code block?

Comment: What does "run the code" entail exactly?

Comment: Which module are you talking about?

Comment: It's a custom module @Clive I want to run a series of functions in the background. It's an Oauth2 scenario where I want to get the response, request a token, and log the user in in the background.

Comment: @brotherpere a custom one

Comment: You can redirect users to different paths accordingly to their roles easily. Will that help you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the background" - in the background of what? Do you mean on a cron job? Something else? That also doesn't seem to relate to your original question, which is about running code for a specific path...

Comment: @brotherpere no, sorry, I don't know the best way to articulate this. Users will be redirected to my site as part of an Oauth2 scenario, based on the query parameters appended to the redirect URL, I need to send a post request to get an auth token, submit the auth token for user data, and use the user data to log the user in. So, I don't need to redirect the users anywhere, I want them to end up on that page, but I need to run the authorization steps before they can actually access the site.

Comment: @Clive, sorry, I'm having trouble articulating this: by the "background" I mean without the users direct involvement. I'm trying to run the authorization and login steps as a part of an oauth flow. I want to respond to the provided query parameters in the redirect url, so my assumption is that I need to run a script on the path of the redirect url. As far as the user knows, they've just agreed to authorize my application. Submitting their creds redirects to my path with a code, I assume I need to run the rest of my auth/login process code at the path where the query params are provided. or no?

Comment: You're probably overthinking it, that's very straightforward: implement `hook_menu()`, add a route with a path that corresponds to the one the 3rd party will be sending requests to, see what's in the query args in the page callback, then react however you need

Comment: Pretty much what Clive said. Implement a hook, give it a callback, double-check/sanitize those inputs. There is no script, its just a PHP function you specify in the menu item array. There are also hooks for users that are authorizing and logging in as well.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should add that I want to do this to an existing page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OAuth2 Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_authentication). Some details about it, from its project page:

> ... allows users to log into your Drupal site authenticating against a remote identity provider (IDP) via OAuth2.
>
> That is, if a user's credentials can be used to retrieve a valid access token, he/she will be logged into the site with those credentials and the token will be added to his/her session. If the user doesn't exist yet, it will be created.

Comment: I'll look at this again, but my initial experiments didn't produce the results I wanted.

Comment: Keep me posted with the problem you encounter. Here to help.

Comment: Appreciate it! I won't be able to dive in a for a few hours, I'm slacking at the day job.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. This solves part of my problem, but does quite offer the functionality I need. It seems that by default the Oauth2 Auth module checks every user against the oauth server, whereas I want to have this functionality for a subset of users. The current config also has the user and pass form, which uses the user-pass flow which I want to avoid. I hope this module will help me sort out of the login and management of the user while their signed in. Fingers crossed. I'm currently looking at user_external_login_register

Comment: Was this the answer to your problem?

Comment: Not really. This module provides a blueprint but doesn’t meet my requirements. To the question I don’t think you can tack on functions to an existing menu without modifying the original menu. I just changed the redirect